# Question about prime numbers $p$ and $q$ and the sum $= p+q$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

My question: If $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers and $4/q^3 = p^2/50$, what is the value of $(p+q)$?

I rearranged the question to get $p^2 * q^3 = 200$.  I do not know what to do after that. Thanks.

Comment: try factoring $200$

Comment: "I rearranged the question to get $p^2∗q^3=200$" Then you are pretty much done.  $200$ has a unique prime factorization.  That that factorization *must* be $p^2q^3$ if this question is fair.

Comment: Thank you so much. How do you know it will have a unique factorization?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

The unique prime factorization of $200$ is $5^22^3$.

Comment: Thank you so much. How do you know it will have a unique prime factorization?

Comment: By the so-called [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)